# Can't get Data Store working in Sencha Touch with scripttag Proxy and JSONP

Tags: web-services, json, sencha-touch

I've got a panel that is supposed to be consuming JSONP from an external web service.

**models/VimeoModel.js**

```
rpc.models.VimeoModel = Ext.regModel('rpc.models.VimeoModel', {
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'title', type: 'string'}
    ]
});
```

**views/VideoView.js**

```
rpc.views.VideoView = new Ext.Panel({
    id: 'VideoView',
    title: "Videos",
    tpl: VimeoTemplate,
    iconCls: "tv",
    dockedItems: [{ xtype: "toolbar", title: "Videos"}],
    store: 'rpc.stores.VimeoStore'
});
```

**stores/VimeoStore.js**

```
rpc.stores.VimeoStore = new Ext.data.Store({
    id: 'VimeoStore',
    model: 'rpc.models.VimeoModel',
    proxy: {
        type: 'scripttag',
        url: WebService.Url + WebService.Vimeo.Read,
        reader: {
            type: 'jsonp',
            root: 'results'
        }
    },
    autoLoad: true
});
```

**templates/VimeoTemplate.js**

```
var VimeoTemplate = new Ext.XTemplate([
    '<tpl for=".">',
        '<div>',
            '{title}',
        '</div>',
    '</tpl>'
]);
```

Unfortunately when the page loads, there is no data being populated into the VideoView.

The WebService request looks like this
http://rpc.infinitas.ws/Vimeo/Read?_dc=1308067234445&limit=25&callback=stcCallback1001
*It's returning a JSONP response*

```
stcCallback1001({"results":[{"id":25036464,"title":"Power of A Surrendered Li..."},{"id":25036610,"title":"Child Dedication June 2011"},{"id":24734142,"title":"Power of A Surrendered Li..."},{"id":24884833,"title":"Finance Update June 2011"},{"id":24587711,"title":"Papua, Indonesia Sharing ..."},{"id":24232427,"title":"ICHTHUS: Coming King"},{"id":23868560,"title":"ICHTHUS: Healer"},{"id":23486615,"title":"ICHTHUS: Sanctifier"},{"id":23211649,"title":"ICHTHUS: Saviour"},{"id":23867961,"title":"Elder Announcement re: Br..."},{"id":22998163,"title":"Triumph of Grace: Risen L..."},{"id":23687914,"title":"Triumph of Grace: Reignin..."},{"id":23692076,"title":"KINGDOM now: For Thine Is..."},{"id":23694183,"title":"KINGDOM now: Deliver Us F..."}],"success":true});stcCallback1001({"results":[{"id":25036464,"title":"Power of A Surrendered Li..."},{"id":25036610,"title":"Child Dedication June 2011"},{"id":24734142,"title":"Power of A Surrendered Li..."},{"id":24884833,"title":"Finance Update June 2011"},{"id":24587711,"title":"Papua, Indonesia Sharing ..."},{"id":24232427,"title":"ICHTHUS: Coming King"},{"id":23868560,"title":"ICHTHUS: Healer"},{"id":23486615,"title":"ICHTHUS: Sanctifier"},{"id":23211649,"title":"ICHTHUS: Saviour"},{"id":23867961,"title":"Elder Announcement re: Br..."},{"id":22998163,"title":"Triumph of Grace: Risen L..."},{"id":23687914,"title":"Triumph of Grace: Reignin..."},{"id":23692076,"title":"KINGDOM now: For Thine Is..."},{"id":23694183,"title":"KINGDOM now: Deliver Us F..."}],"success":true});
```

When I fire up the Chrome Javascript Console I get an error

> Read:1 Uncaught ReferenceError:stcCallback1001 is not defined

And here's the staging app if you need more info
http://rpcm.infinitas.ws

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the javascript you're returning.  You're outputting the callback twice.  If you click on the jsonp link in your question you should see two stcCallback1001 invocations.  Since the callback is removed after the first one the second one fails.

BTW You don't need to specify the callbackParam.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried your suggestion and also updated my question for clarity. Unfortunately I'm still in a jam.

Comment: sorry, I thought it was a random number, turns out it's consistently `stcCallback1001` - I'll edit my question once more.

Comment: If I add `callbackParam: 'idSession',` to the proxy, then the "not defined" error goes away, but instead I get "TypeError: number is not a function".

Comment: I'm still getting the error... **Uncaught ReferenceError: stcCallback1001 is not defined**

Comment: ah, I see what you mean now. I can't figure out how that's getting in there.

Answer (score 0):

See the answer I provided on your other question, [Sencha Touch JSONP Store Data not showing up in Panel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352466/sencha-touch-jsonp-store-data-not-showing-up-in-panel).

The main issue is that you want to change the proxy from `type: 'scripttag'` to `type: 'jsonp'`. Once you do that, the JSONP proxy should take care of creating the appropriate callback functions before it makes the request to the server.

Comment: Also note that you need to remove the `callback` param from your URL. The JSONP Proxy will add that itself. It creates a function for handling the response and will need to specify that in the request params. If you're also setting it, then the server will end up with two values and might behave oddly, such as creating two responses.

Answer (score -1):

Making the reader type from 'jsonp to 'json' should bring back the correct result.

Comment: jsonp is required in order to prevent Cross Domain Request Errors.